ssue with PulseUI on Fedora: Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF) installation fails during package verification in setup_cef.sh
I am trying to install the Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF) for PulseUI on Fedora using the provided setup_cef.sh script, but the installation fails during the package verification step with the following error:
./setup_cef.sh: line 353: -a: command not found
Error: Download package file verification failed. Please try again

The script seems to download the necessary CEF binaries without any issues, but the verification step fails, and the installation is aborted. Here's the relevant portion of the output:
Downloading CEF from https://pcstp.pulsesecure.net/cef/linux/cef64.94.tar.bz2...
Download successful
Validating the downloaded package...
./setup_cef.sh: line 353: -a: command not found
Error: Download package file verification failed. Please try again

I've verified that I have sufficient disk space, and all the required tools like curl, tar, and bzip2 are installed. The issue seems to stem from the script itself.
Has anyone else encountered this problem? What would be the correct way to resolve this issue?

When I came across this recently, I had a look at the script.
It wants to use a binary called shasum generate the hash and compare to the downloaded file.
I am new to RHEL, and looked around the installed packages and came across sha1sum. A solution I found was to softlink one to the other, but that failed as the argument was not expected by sha1sum.
The first result of dnf search SHA1 was Perl-Digest-SHA1. I also checked to see what other packages could provide that with dnf provides shasum, which returned the same.
Installing that with sudo dnf install Perl-Digest-SHA1 installed the required package and I could then install the CEF with:
cd /opt/pulsesecure/bin
./setup_cef.sh install

Hope this gets you over the line.
